# Automatically generate build number based on timestamp with WiX 3.6

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wix, wix3.6

I found a number of ways to automatically increment build numbers with Team build setup environments, but none of them are satisfying for me, because I have a C++ MFC application where most of the approaches won't work.

So I thought about another solution, that might work for our team (since it is not that big):

I want to have a build number like this:

```
$(major).$(minor).$(buildnumber) <!-- where buildnumber is like YYMMDDHHMM -->
```

I think `$(major)` and `$(minor)` can be set using preprocessor variables from the command line (or pre-build tasks like grepping them from a file and putting them into variables), but the build number is the one that should be unique based on the build.

This approach would work for each developer on his local machine as well as in the CI environment (TFS in our case).

Is there a way to achieve this? Or is there another idea to automatically generate increased build numbers (not necesarrily based on a timestamp) I did not see yet?

Comment: Why is this question tagged wix?

Comment: If you are passing this to the installer as the product version, your $(buildnumber) is too big, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370859(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation of this requirement involves two parts:

1) The build automation generating a ProductVerion property

2) The build automation passing this property into the WiX build.

For #1, I like to use [TFS Versioning](http://tfsversioning.codeplex.com/) but there are many solutions out there that will do what you want.

For #2, I put code like this in the .wixproj:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
   <MSIProductVersion Condition=" '$(MSIProductVersion)' == '' ">0.1.0</MSIProductVersion>
 </PropertyGroup>

 <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' ">
   <DefineConstants>Debug;WiXProductVersion=$(MSIProductVersion)</DefineConstants>
 </PropertyGroup>
 <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' ">
   <DefineConstants>WiXProductVersion=$(MSIProductVersion)</DefineConstants>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

In the actual wxs I do this:

```
 <Product Id="*" Name="IsWiX" Language="1033" Version="$(var.WiXProductVersion)"
          Manufacturer="ISWIX LLC" UpgradeCode="some upgrade code">
   <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" />
```

The concept is TFS passes in MSIProductVersion and this gets passed into the compiler and mapped to the Version attribute.  For local developer builds the MSI just get's 0.1.0 as the version ( a good indicator that it's not an official build ).

Comment: Thanks for the link to the TfsVersioning project, but I'm afraid this is not capable of supporting unmanaged C++ projects (there is no AssemblyInfo handling in my case). But I'll investigate anyways.

Comment: As I said, there are many ways to skin this cat.  I was mainly trying to demonstrate the concept that generating a version number and stamping a verion number are two differenct activities and to show how to stamp a WiX MSI.   A google search of vs_version_info shows many hits including this interesting one: http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2011/09/05/tfs-2010-build-numbers-file-versions-from-inside-your-c-and-c-projects.aspx

Comment: Now that link looks very promising. I tried with adding a custom workflow with custom activities that were able to set readonly flags on files, modify version info in files matched by a pattern and so on using [Richard Banks' hint](http://www.richard-banks.org/2010/07/how-to-versioning-builds-with-tfs-2010.html), but this approach is way more convenient. Great answer!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the "verbuild.exe" utility found [here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/v-s/devstudio_macros/add-ins/article.php/c14453/Auto-Increment-the-Version-Number-after-Each-Build-in-a-Visual-Studio-Project.htm)

Follow steps from that page:

1. Create initial version header file: `verbuild <version header file> -c`
2. Create a resource (.rc) file that:

   1. Includes the header file from step 1
   2. Includes the changes to replace proper versions in the .rc file using those from the header file (e.g., `VERSION_FILE`)
3. Change build to call `verbuild` to update the build number before building the projet:

   - I run a batch file to increment the build number: `verbuild <version header file> %1 -xFP`